# Where are literal float/int constants stored in Cuda

Tags: cuda

Are literal constants encountered in kernels stored in constant memory? E.g.,

```
y = x * 3.14f; // x,y are floats.
```

Is `3.14f` stored in constant memory and copied into register before multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

According to my testing, that constant seems to be encoded in the instruction stream (i.e. it is fetched along with instructions):

```
$ cat t1799.cu
__global__ void k(float *d){

  float y, x = *d;
  y = x * 3.14f;
  *d = y;
}
$ nvcc -c t1799.cu
$ cuobjdump -sass t1799.o

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_30
code version = [1,7]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

        code for sm_30
                Function : _Z1kPf
        .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM30 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM30)"
                                                                           /* 0x22f04283f2804307 */
        /*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x44];                   /* 0x2800400110005de4 */
        /*0010*/                   MOV R2, c[0x0][0x140];                  /* 0x2800400500009de4 */
        /*0018*/                   MOV R3, c[0x0][0x144];                  /* 0x280040051000dde4 */
        /*0020*/                   LD.E R0, [R2];                          /* 0x8400000000201c85 */
        /*0028*/                   FMUL32I R4, R0, 3.1400001049041748047;  /* 0x310123d70c011c02 */
        /*0030*/                   ST.E [R2], R4;                          /* 0x9400000000211c85 */
        /*0038*/                   EXIT;                                   /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
        /*0040*/                   BRA 0x40;                               /* 0x4003ffffe0001de7 */
        /*0048*/                   NOP;                                    /* 0x4000000000001de4 */
        /*0050*/                   NOP;                                    /* 0x4000000000001de4 */
        /*0058*/                   NOP;                                    /* 0x4000000000001de4 */
        /*0060*/                   NOP;                                    /* 0x4000000000001de4 */
        /*0068*/                   NOP;                                    /* 0x4000000000001de4 */
        /*0070*/                   NOP;                                    /* 0x4000000000001de4 */
        /*0078*/                   NOP;                                    /* 0x4000000000001de4 */
                .................



Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_30
code version = [6,5]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed
$
```

You can probably do this kind of analysis yourself if you spend some time with the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html)

The main instructions of interest are these:

```
        /*0020*/      LD.E R0, [R2]; // float y, x = *d;  R0 is x
        /*0028*/      FMUL32I R4, R0, 3.1400001049041748047; // y = x * 3.14f; R4 is y
        /*0030*/      ST.E [R2], R4;   //       *d = y;
```

The instruction syntax `FMUL32I R4, R0, 3.1400001049041748047;` makes it clear that the `3.14` constant is encoded as an immediate operand in the instruction:

```
 FMUL32I
 ||  | Immediate
 ||  32-bit
 |Multiply
 Floating point
```

The code *is* accessing constant memory in the first 3 instructions of the kernel, however the only thing meaningful there is:

```
MOV R2, c[0x0][0x140];
```

which is loading the address of the `d` parameter into a register for a register-indirect load.  None of those loads from constant memory have anything to do with the `3.14` constant.

> Is 3.14f stored in constant memory

No.

> and copied into register before multiplication?

No.